# Determining structure of string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get my head around using regex to obtain the structure of a string (and then use that structure to randomly generate a string of the same structure), but it's the structure identification I'm struggling to understand.

The input string is essentially a mask, which can be any number of `a`s or `0`s, signifying that the character should be a letter or a number in the generated string respectively.

For example, the input string could be anything like the following:

```
aaa000
00aaaa0
aa00a0aa
0a0a0a
aaaaa0
0aaaaa
000000
aaaaaa
```

Ideally, I'd like to have a regex expression that gives me (for the first example) `/\w{3}\d{3}/`, which I can then use to generate a new string. I'm not having trouble with the generation, just the detection.

Any string containing any other character than `a` or `0` shouldn't match.

I'm pretty new to learning regex and honestly wouldn't know where to start. What would be the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your generation algorithm works, but shouldn't it be able to deal with this:

```
str_replace(['a', '0'], ['\\w', '\\d'], $str); // aaa000 -> \w\w\w\d\d\d
```

(Also keep in mind that `\w` matches numbers as well.)

Comment: Great idea! I hadn't thought of this and was evidently reading way too far into it. Thanks for the heads up about `\w`, didn't know that. Would `/D` be the most appropriate to use for a letter?

Comment: @AlexGodbehere `\w` matches `\d` so it would be better to use `[a-z]` explicitly.